# Compute limit of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Compute: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\arctan(e^x+\arctan x)-\arctan(e^{\sin x}+\arctan(\sin x))}{x^3}$$ 
WolframAlpha tells me it's 1/6. Any nice idea how to rewrite that expression? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can proceed as follows $$\begin{aligned}L\, &= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan^{-1}(e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x) - \tan^{-1}(e^{\sin x} + \tan^{-1}(\sin x))}{x^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x - e^{\sin x} - \tan^{-1}(\sin x)}{1 + (e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x)(e^{\sin x} + \tan^{-1}(\sin x))}\right)}{x^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}\cdot\dfrac{t}{x^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{t}{x^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x - e^{\sin x} - \tan^{-1}(\sin x)}{1 + (e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x)(e^{\sin x} + \tan^{-1}(\sin x))}\right)}{x^{3}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x - e^{\sin x} - \tan^{-1}(\sin x)}{x^{3}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{x} - e^{\sin x}}{x^{3}} + \frac{\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}(\sin x)}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{\sin x}(e^{x - 
\sin x} - 1)}{x^{3}} + \dfrac{\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x - \sin x}{1 + x\sin x}\right)}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{\sin x}(e^{x - 
\sin x} - 1)}{x^{3}} + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x - \sin x}{1 + x\sin x}\right)}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{(e^{x - 
\sin x} - 1)}{x^{3}} + \lim_{v \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}v}{v}\cdot\frac{v}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{u \to 0^{+}}\frac{(e^{u} - 1)}{u}\cdot\frac{u}{x^{3}} + \lim_{v \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}v}{v}\cdot\frac{v}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}} + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{(1 + x\sin x)x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}} + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1 - \cos x}{3x^{2}}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\cdot 2\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{6}\end{aligned}$$ We have used subsitutions $$t = \dfrac{e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x - e^{\sin x} - \tan^{-1}(\sin x)}{1 + (e^{x} + \tan^{-1}x)(e^{\sin x} + \tan^{-1}(\sin x))}, u = x - \sin x, v = \dfrac{x - \sin x}{1 + x\sin x}$$ and each of these variables $t, u, v$ tends to $0$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and hence we have $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t} = 1,\,\lim_{u \to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{u} - 1}{u} = 1,\, \lim_{v \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan^{-1}v}{v} = 1$$ The above derivation shows that the normal rules of algebra of limits coupled with few standard limit formulas can handle very complicated expressions and the use of LHR can be minimized to cases where it is really necessary.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Write the limit as:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(e^x+\tan^{-1}x)-\tan^{-1}(e^{\sin x}+\tan^{-1}\sin x)}{x - \sin x} \cdot \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(e^x+\tan^{-1}x)-\tan^{-1}(e^{\sin x}+\tan^{-1}\sin x)}{x - \sin x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$

Use the mean value theorem for the first limit and L'Hopital's Rule for the second.

EDIT: Let me elaborate on the first limit. Set $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(e^x + \tan^{-1}x)$.

Then, $\dfrac{f(x)-f(\sin x)}{x-\sin x} = f'(c_x)$ where $\sin x < c_x < x$. Clearly, $c_x$ depends on $x$.

However using the squeeze theorem, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}c_x = 0$. Do you see how to continue?

Comment: It would be nice if you explain how to apply MWT in this case

Comment: The numerator is of the form $f(x)-f(\sin x)$, where $f(x)=\arctan(e^x+\arctan x)$. @user146371